# type error dialog.showmessageBoxSync is not a function

Tags: electron, windows-10, undefined-function

I just started using electron and fail to use `showmessageBoxSync`: it returns the error:

> type error dialog.showmessageBoxSync is not a function

isn't `showmessageBoxSync` a member of `dialog` which is a property of returned object returned by `require('electron');`? what am I missing? the dialog variable is declared as:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron');
```

this is the full code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');

function newApp() {
        
  dialog.showmessageBoxSync({
    message: 'hello world'
  });
  
  win = new BrowserWindow();
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: "index.html",
      slashes: true
    })
  );
  
  win.on('closed', () => {
      win = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", newApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is [`dialog.showMessageBoxSync`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxsyncbrowserwindow-options), with a capital M.

Comment: oh, how ridiculous was my question. I guess i'm too tired

Comment: @Jack No worries, we've all been there :D